# Why UPS are not DC output?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ups, dc-ac

A seemingly simple question that bothers me for some time: why the simplest, mass-produced, "offline" (standby) Uninterruptible Power Supplies designed for PC are not having simple DC voltage output (say 300 VDC for Europe)? Because switching power supplies used in PC and monitor sure can work on DC input.

I don't think that an incompatibility with the PFC is the reason because:

1. Some PC power supply does not even include active PFC
2. Some do, but operate properly on DC anyway
3. Some others do, but have problems with "quasi-sine" waveform from these UPS anyway

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Several things. Start with this one: https://youtu.be/Zez2r1RPpWY

Comment: How would you prevent someone plugging in something that doesn't use a SMPS into the UPS?

Comment: Datacentres are taking a close look at DC distribution for many reasons, not least because it simplifies the UPS implementation for their particular needs. http://www.datacenterdynamics.com/content-tracks/design-build/dc-distribution-is-not-just-for-the-giants/95037.fullarticle

Comment: @tangrs to prevent AC devices to be plugged into DC output the UPS can use a different plug specifically for DC output; can come up with standard say USB for 5v and some new ones for 3v and 12v.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious thing that you are missing is that many devices will be destroyed if you apply a DC power supply to them.

Most older electronic devices use a power transformer to convert the incoming voltage to the levels required by the device. Applying DC to such a device will damage or destroy it.

Most consumers don't know if their devices can accept a DC supply. And because the power connection is the same for all of those devices, it would be not unreasonable for a consumer to plug their device into the UPS.

Can you say  "Class Action Lawsuit"?

Comment: Can have a different plug to output DC so that user won't power AC devices with it.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the other answers and comments:

Because not every SMPS takes DC. A PFC (power factor correction) circuit looks very different if it has to be DC compatible. And as most devices with a power more than some 10 W has to provide a PFC nowadays by regulatory statements, you will encounter a whole lot of SMPS which aren't capable of taking DC as DC compatibility of PFCs is a serious cost factor.

Furthermore, you simply aren't allowed to provide DC power over standardised wall outlets. The outlets are standardised to serve all mains powered devices without burning down the hut where they are installed.

On the contrary you will find a lot of fixed installed UPSes in buildings for emergency lighting which in fact deliver DC to their designated luminaires and control devices. Those circuits are subject to special codes and regulations, though. Just google "CEAG"

Comment: I agree not every SMPS takes DC but the motherboard does, I wonder and probably @Cubrilo too why not connect the DC output from UPS to a motherboard, this will avoid DC(from UPS)-AC-DC(SMPS) conversion.

Comment: PFC is a DC-DC boost converter. I cannot claim for all PFC circuits in the world, but all that I've seen worked fine with DC input. Typical off-the-shelf AC-DC converter has input voltage range 90~264VAC 127~370VDC.

Comment: @ArvindSingh That's a different question. When powering a mobo directly you need two vor more different DC voltages. Thus making an UPS overly complex.